# Adjective for the unfortunate side of having a "good sense of smell"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

*(Anecdotal kickoff)*

I recently moved to a new town. While visiting, my mom -- who has a particularly good sense of smell -- noted a constant foulness in the air that I've been unable to pick up on. Clearly, having such an heightened sense of smell can be both a blessing and a curse.

I'm struggling to come up with an adjective that concisely describes this situation. In general, I would call this a "good nose," "sensitive nose," or even "astute nose." **None of these quite grasp the light, but empathic tone I'm looking for.**

Is there an adjective out there that fits?

Bonus points to whoever can up with a contrasting adjective for my comparatively stunted sense of smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a comparison or simile would serve you better here than an adjective:

> Her sense of smell is as keen as a great white shark's.

for example, or

> She has a nose like a bloodhound's.

although the latter may cause people who've never seen your mother to imagine her with a long snout, droopy ears, and doleful eyes.

My wife's sense of smell far surpasses that of anyone else in our family, and when she makes a pronouncement based on her olfactory acuteness, we simply say, "The nose knows."

Answer (score 1):

There are two adjectives that indicate a good sense of smell but not very useful for an everyday speech:

***sharp-nosed***

> having a keen or sensitive sense of smell.
>
> <sup>http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sharp-nosed</sup>

*Sharp-nosed* is not common in this sense and it is usually used to mean a thin, pointed nose.

***osmatic***

> Having or characterized by a well-developed sense of smell.
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/osmatic</sup>

And *osmatic* is usually used in medicine and biology. [Another related term is *hyperosmia* (*hyperosmic* as an adjective) which is an increased olfactory acuity (heightened sense of smell), usually caused by a lower threshold for odor - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperosmia)]

In the end, your best bet might be not using a single word but saying "having a good sense of smell" or "having a strong sense of smell". Or maybe a simile like "having the nose of a hound".

Comment: I don't know: anyone using _hyperosmic_ conversationally is bound to be considered funny.

Comment: I would just say 'My friend, who is cursed with the nose of a sniffer-dog, is forced to live with a foul-smelling environment'

Comment: *Osmatic* sounds very similar to both *osmotic* and *asthmatic*, and would easily be mistaken for either of those words — especially as it is so rarely encountered in general usage.

Answer (score 0):

The term that immediately comes to mind is:

Super-sniffer

Notably it is used in the TV show Psych for the character Burton Guster and his extra-ordinary ability to notice and identify smells which other normal people who are comparatively smelling-impaired cannot.